# How to add horizontal lines in ganttchart?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfgantt

I am trying to make a ganttchart using the `pgfgantt` package in Overleaf. I have a problem I have not managed to fix.
I would like to add horizontal lines below each group.
To explain myself better.
I get this:
[image: What I get]

And I would like this:
[image: What I want]

This is the beginning of the ganttchart Specs I am using: I am adding this in a thesis document with `\documentclass{book}`. I have included the packages  I think are the ones related to the ganttchart, in order to simplify the big number of packages included in the project.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{import}

\ganttset{group/.append style={black}, milestone/.append style={red},
 progress label node anchor/.append style={text=red}}

\begin{document}

 \begin{ganttchart}[%Specs
 y unit title=0.5cm,
 y unit chart=0.7cm,
 hgrid={*1{black}, *7{dotted}, *1{black},  *6{dotted}},
 vgrid, 
 x unit=0.5cm,
 title height=1,
 title label font=\bfseries\footnotesize,
 bar/.style={fill=lightgray},
 bar height=0.4,
 group right shift=0,
 group top shift=0.7,
 group height=.3,
 group peaks width={0.2},
 inline
 bar label node/.append style={text width=15cm},
 group label node/.append style={text width=15cm},
 milestone label node/.append style={text width=15cm},
 bar label node/.append style={align=left, text width=width("longest text I have")},
 ]{1}{12}  

\ganttgroup[inline=false]{{Obj. 1: Some text in here}}{1}{3}\\
\ganttbar[inline=false]{Task 1.1: Some text in here}{1}{1}\\
\ganttbar[inline=false]{Task 1.2: Some text in here}{1}{2}\\
\ganttbar[inline=false]{Task 1.3: Some text in here}{2}{2}\\
\ganttbar[inline=false]{Task 1.4: Some text in here}{2}{3}\\
\ganttbar[inline=false]{Task 1.5: CSome text in here}{3}{4}\\
\ganttbar[inline=false]{\textit{Paper 1}}{4}{4}\\
\ganttnewline


 \end{ganttchart}
 \end{document}
```

After the `\ganttnewline` space, I would like to add an horizontal line in the text.

Comment: Thank you Alan Munn. I hope the extra clarification help to understand better the problem I have.

Comment: Thanks for the update. (Still missing `\documentclass`). This code seems to end up off the page on the right for me.

Comment: \documetclass{book} I wrote it in the text. I did not understand, what you mean with "his code seems to end up off the page on the right for me"

Comment: By using `text width=15cm` in your code you push the chart off of the edge of the page in the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SE. The lines can be added with `\ganttnewline`, which accepts optional formating keys such as the line thickness and colour, like this: `\ganttnewline[very thick, blue]`. Without setting any keys for the `\draw` command used by `\ganttnewline`, no line is drawn. See section 2.4 of the `pgfgantt` manual.

The left starting position of the line was adapted by measuring the length of the longest bar label, which was then stored in `\myleft` like this:
`\pgfmathsetmacro\myleft{width("Task 1.1: Some text in here")+10pt}`.
We then renew the `\ganttnewline` command to use `\myleft` as the starting point of the line (a comment in the MWE indicates where this replacement occurs).

Other cleanup included removing one of the two `bar label node` keys since one had `text width=15cm` and the other was measuring the width as described above. Generally, you only need to define the width of the longest label, whether it is the `group label`, `bar label` or `milestone label`. Here, the `bar label` has the longest label so the text width settings for `group label node` and `milestone label node` are redundant and can be removed also.

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=3pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\ganttset{group/.append style={black},
          milestone/.append style={red},
          progress label node anchor/.append style={text=red}}

% Find the left edge of the bar label by measuring the width of the longest label, and add 10pt
\pgfmathsetmacro\myleft{width("Task 1.1: Some text in here")+10pt}
% Redefine \ganttnewline to draw a line from a position equal to the length of the longest label 
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\ganttnewline[1][]{%
\begingroup%
\def\local@drawarg{#1}%
\def\@tempa{grid}%
\ifx\local@drawarg\@empty\else%
\ifx\local@drawarg\@tempa%
\def\local@drawarg{/pgfgantt/hgrid style}% 
\fi%
\pgfmathsetmacro\y@upper{%
\gtt@lasttitleline * \ganttvalueof{y unit title}%
+ (\gtt@currentline - \gtt@lasttitleline - 1)%
* \ganttvalueof{y unit chart}%
}
\expandafter\draw\expandafter[\local@drawarg]
(-\myleft pt, \y@upper pt) --  %<-- -\myleft pt replaces 0pt, which starts the line from the left edge of the canvas.
(\gtt@chartwidth * \ganttvalueof{x unit}, \y@upper pt);%
\fi%
\global\advance\gtt@currentline by-1\relax%
\ifgtt@intitle\global\advance\gtt@lasttitleline by-1\relax\fi%
\global\gtt@lasttitleslot=0\relax%
\endgroup%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

 \begin{ganttchart}[%Specs
 y unit title=0.5cm,
 y unit chart=0.7cm,
 hgrid={*1{black}, *7{dotted}, *1{black},  *6{dotted}},
 vgrid,
 x unit=0.5cm,
 title height=1,
 title label font=\bfseries\footnotesize,
 bar/.style={fill=lightgray},
 bar height=0.4,
 inline=false,
 group label node/.append style={align=left,text width=width("Task 1.1: Some text in here ")},
 bar label node/.append style={align=left,text width=width("Task 1.1: Some text in here ")},
 ]{1}{12}

\ganttgroup{Literature review}{1}{3} \ganttnewline[very thick, blue]
\ganttbar{Obj. 1: Some text in here}{1}{1}\\
\ganttbar{Task 1.1: Some text in here}{1}{1}\\ 
\ganttbar{Task 1.2: Some text in here}{1}{2}\\
\ganttbar{Task 1.3: Some text in here}{2}{2}\\
\ganttbar{Task 1.4: Some text in here}{2}{3}\\
\ganttbar{Task 1.5: Some text in here}{3}{4}\\
\ganttbar{\textit{Paper 1}}{4}{4} \ganttnewline[very thick, red]
\ganttbar{Task 1.1: Some text in here}{1}{1}
\end{ganttchart}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 very nice. You might want to add a comment about the `text width` parameters you removed in the example that made the OPs code produce odd output.

Comment: Thanks @Alan. Done.

Comment: Super!! Thank you very much Ross!! It looks perfect now :) !!