# Gantt chart - borders and heading for task list and spacing in lines

Tags: pgfgantt, gantt

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
% Uncomment the following line to allow the usage of graphics (.png, .jpg)
%\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
% Comment the following line to NOT allow the usage of umlauts

\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\title{Gantt chart showing PhD activity time lines over four month intervals beyond the confirmation review}

\usepackage{amsfonts}

% Start the document
\begin{document}

\definecolor{barblue}{RGB}{153,204,254}
\definecolor{groupblue}{RGB}{51,102,254}
\definecolor{linkred}{RGB}{165,0,33}
\renewcommand\sfdefault{phv}
\renewcommand\mddefault{mc}
\renewcommand\bfdefault{bc}
\setganttlinklabel{s-s}{START-TO-START}
\setganttlinklabel{f-s}{FINISH-TO-START}
\setganttlinklabel{f-f}{FINISH-TO-FINISH}
\sffamily
\begin{ganttchart}[
  [
    canvas/.append style={fill=none, draw=black!5, line width=.75pt},
    hgrid style/.style={*1{draw=black!5, line width=.75pt}},
    vgrid={*1{draw=black!5, line width=.75pt}},
    today=7,
    today rule/.style={
      draw=black!64,
      dash pattern=on 3.5pt off 6.5pt,
      line width=1.5pt
    },
    today label font=\small\bfseries,
    title/.style={draw=none, fill=none},
    title label font=\bfseries\footnotesize,
    title label node/.append style={below=7pt},
    include title in canvas=false,
    bar label font=\mdseries\small\color{black!70},
    bar label node/.append style={left=2cm},
    bar/.append style={draw=none, fill=black!63},
    bar incomplete/.append style={fill=barblue},
    bar progress label font=\mdseries\footnotesize\color{black!70},
    group incomplete/.append style={fill=groupblue},
    group left shift=0,
    group right shift=0,
    group height=.5,
    group peaks tip position=0,
    group label node/.append style={left=.6cm},
    group progress label font=\bfseries\small,
    link/.style={-latex, line width=1.5pt, linkred},
    link label font=\scriptsize\bfseries, 
    link label node/.append style={below left=-2pt and 0pt}
  ]{1}{41}
  \gantttitle[
   ]{QUARTER:\quad1}{2}
  \gantttitle{2022}{12}                        
  \gantttitle{2023}{12}
    \gantttitle{2024}{12} \\  
    \gantttitle{Q3}{4}           
  \gantttitle{Q4}{4}
  \gantttitle{Q1}{4}
  \gantttitle{Q2}{4}
  \gantttitle{Q3}{4}
  \gantttitle{Q4}{4}
  \gantttitle{Q1}{4}
  \gantttitle{Q2}{4}
  \gantttitle{Q3}{4}
  \gantttitle{Q4}{4}
\\

  \ganttbar[
    progress=100,
    name=WBS1A
  ]{\textbf{Literature review \& thesis aims clarification }} {1}{4} \\
    \ganttbar[
    progress=100,
    name=WBS1A
  ]{\textbf{To carry out a comprehensive check whether the Lagrangian self-consistently implies the correct physics via its resulting Euler-Lagrange equations}}{3}{5}\\
  \ganttbar[
    progress=100,
    name=WBS1D
  ]{\textbf{to address HAVING IDENITIFIED X XANNOATE SOLUITON HODGE PR SOMEHTIGN  the short-comings of the article in the BOTHEJM/B-paper}}{4}{6} \\
   \ganttbar[
    progress=0,
    name=WBS1C
  ]{\textbf{Paper preperation and submission: Hodge decomposition, suggestion of a Lagrangian and computing the Euler-Lagrange equations}}{6}{8} \\
    \ganttbar[
    progress=100,
    name=WBS1A
  ]{\textbf{To work out a systematic approach based on the second variation technique by which in case of compressible flow a linear acoustic model is obtained straight forwardly from an arbitrary Lagrangian}}{3}{4} \\
  \ganttbar[
    progress=100,
    name=WBS1B
  ]{\textbf{To apply the forementioned approach developed in to our Lagrangian and compare with classical results }}{4}{5} \\
 
   \ganttbar[
    progress=100,
    name=WBS1C
  ]{\textbf{to extend the analysis outlined IN TASK X? to weakly nonlinear acoustic models by amending the second variation technique by cubic terms of the respective Taylor expansion}}{4}{5} \\
  \ganttbar[
    progress=0,
    name=WBS1D
  ]{\textbf{Paper preperation and submission: second variational acoustics- linear (both Lagrangians), non-linear from simple Lagrangian}}{7}{9} \\
   \ganttbar[
    progress=0,
    name=NONLAG
  ]{\textbf{ (expect intermediate results)To apply the approach developed in TASK XX OUR Lagrangian, compare the result with existing models in open literature, and to discuss the physical implications of the result}}{6}{12} \\
  
  \ganttbar[
    progress=0,
    name=REL
  ]{\textbf{Paper preperation and submission: second variational acoustics- linear (both Lagrangians), non-linear from simple Lagrangian}}{10}{14} \\
  
     \ganttbar[
    progress=0,name=POI]{\textbf{
 To work out a stability analysis for a simple flow example (Poiseuille, Couette or film flow) based on the second variation technique with comparison to existing stability results in literature}}{14}{18} \\

   
  \ganttbar[
    progress=0,
    name=FEM
  ]{\textbf{to figure out a FEM approach for incompressible flow based on the new Lagrangian (but without implementing a computer code for the latter) for future applications }}{16}{20} \\

  \ganttbar[progress=15]{\textbf{Thesis writing / and submission}}{1}{41} \\
   \ganttbar[progress=15]{\textbf{Oral Exam}}{40}{41}
   

  \ganttlink[link type=s-s]{POI}{FEM}
 
  %\ganttlink[link type=f-s]{NONLAG}{REL}
  \ganttlink[link type=f-s]{REL}{POI}
 
 
\end{ganttchart}

\end{document}
```

[image]

1. I would like to have the entire Gantt chart bordered, including the heading quarter and the labels of the Gantt bars.
2. I want to put some of the Gantt bar labels over two lines. \\ does not work.
3. I would like the heading TASKS above the Gantt bar labels.

How can I do this please?

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to TeX.SE. The bar labels are nodes so you need to assign an alignment to get a line break, like this, by right aligning the bar labels (thanks @Jasper):

```
bar label node/.append style={left=2cm,align=right}
```

Then you can just use `\\` to break the line at the desired point in the bar label.

You can bold each of the node labels like this (you don't have to use `\textbf` in each bar label):

```
bar label font=\bfseries\small\color{black!70}, %<-- \bfseries
```

Add "TASKS" manually using:

```
\node [text=blue,font=\Large\bfseries,anchor=east] at (-2,-1.75) {TASKS};
```

Draw a box around the canvas using:

```
\draw[line width=2pt,blue] ([yshift=-1cm]current bounding box.south west) rectangle 
(current bounding box.north east);
```

Add the title using:

```
\node [font=\Large\bfseries] at ([yshift=0.5cm]current bounding box.north) 
{Gantt chart showing PhD activity time lines over four month intervals beyond the 
confirmation review};
```

The line under "TASKS" and each bar label are added with `\myline{line thickness}{line colour}` at the end of each `\ganttbar` command. `\myline{}{}` is an adaption of the hack from here: [How to add horizontal lines in ganttchart?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/498497/).

I also used what I think is a more pleasing heading for the years and quarters.

Good luck with your thesis. Judging by the subject material, learning LaTeX will likely be helpful to you.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3pt]{standalone}
% Uncomment the following line to allow the usage of graphics (.png, .jpg)
%\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
% Comment the following line to NOT allow the usage of umlauts
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
% Start the document
\begin{document}
\definecolor{barblue}{RGB}{153,204,254}
\definecolor{groupblue}{RGB}{51,102,254}
\definecolor{linkred}{RGB}{165,0,33}
\renewcommand\sfdefault{phv}
\renewcommand\mddefault{mc}
\renewcommand\bfdefault{bc}
\setganttlinklabel{s-s}{START-TO-START}
\setganttlinklabel{f-s}{FINISH-TO-START}
\setganttlinklabel{f-f}{FINISH-TO-FINISH}
\sffamily
% Find the left edge of the bar label by measuring the width of the longest label, and add 10pt
\pgfmathsetmacro\myleft{width("To apply the forementioned approach developed in to our Lagrangian and compare with classical results")+2cm}
% Adapt \ganttnewline to draw a line from a position equal to the length of the longest label
\makeatletter
\newcommand*\myline[2][]{%
\begingroup%
\pgfmathsetmacro\y@upper{%
\gtt@lasttitleline * \ganttvalueof{y unit title}%
+ (\gtt@currentline - \gtt@lasttitleline - 1)%
* \ganttvalueof{y unit chart}%
}
\draw[#1,#2]
(-\myleft pt, \y@upper pt) --  %<-- -\myleft pt replaces 0pt, which starts the line from the left edge of the canvas.
(\gtt@chartwidth * \ganttvalueof{x unit}, \y@upper pt);%
\global\advance\gtt@currentline by-1\relax%
\endgroup%
}
\makeatother

\begin{ganttchart}[
  [
   canvas/.append style={fill=none, draw=black!5, line width=.75pt},
    hgrid style/.style={*1{draw=black!5, line width=.75pt}},
    vgrid={*1{draw=black!5, line width=.75pt}},
    today=7,
    today rule/.style={
      draw=black!64,
      dash pattern=on 3.5pt off 6.5pt,
      line width=1.5pt
    },
    today label font=\small\bfseries,
    title/.style={draw=black, fill=none},
    title label font=\bfseries\footnotesize,
    include title in canvas=false,
    bar label node/.append style={left=2cm,align=right},
    bar/.append style={draw=none, fill=black!63},
    bar incomplete/.append style={fill=barblue},
    bar progress label font=\mdseries\footnotesize\color{black!70},
    link/.style={-latex, line width=1.5pt, linkred},
    link label font=\scriptsize\bfseries,
    link label node/.append style={below left=-2pt and 0pt}
  ]{1}{41}
  \gantttitle{2021}{6}
  \gantttitle{2022}{12}
  \gantttitle{2023}{12}
  \gantttitle{2024}{12} \\
  \gantttitlelist{"Q3","Q4","Q1","Q2","Q3","Q4","Q1","Q2","Q3","Q4","Q1","Q2","Q3","Q4"}{3}
  \myline{blue}{thick}
  \ganttbar[
    progress=100,
    name=WBS1A
  ]{Literature review \& thesis aims clarification } {1}{4} \myline{thin}{blue}
    \ganttbar[
    progress=100,
    name=WBS1A
  ]{To carry out a comprehensive check whether the Lagrangian self-consistently\\implies the correct physics via its resulting Euler-Lagrange equations}{3}{5} \myline{thin}{blue}
  \ganttbar[
    progress=100,
    name=WBS1D
  ]{to address HAVING IDENTIFIED X XANNOATE SOLUTION HODGE PR SOMETHING \\the short-comings of the article in the BOTHEJM/B-paper}{4}{6} \myline{thin}{blue}
   \ganttbar[
    progress=0,
    name=WBS1C
  ]{Paper preparation and submission: Hodge decomposition, suggestion of\\a Lagrangian and computing the Euler-Lagrange equations}{6}{8} \myline{thin}{blue}
    \ganttbar[
    progress=100,
    name=WBS1A
  ]{To work out a systematic approach based on the second variation technique by which in case of\\compressible flow a linear acoustic model is obtained straight forwardly from an arbitrary Lagrangian}{3}{4} \myline{thin}{blue}
  \ganttbar[
    progress=100,
    name=WBS1B
  ]{To apply the forementioned approach developed in to our Lagrangian and compare with classical results}{4}{5} \myline{thin}{blue}
   \ganttbar[
    progress=100,
    name=WBS1C
  ]{to extend the analysis outlined IN TASK X? to weakly nonlinear acoustic models by amending the\\second variation technique by cubic terms of the respective Taylor expansion}{4}{5} \myline{thin}{blue}
  \ganttbar[
    progress=0,
    name=WBS1D
  ]{Paper preparation and submission: second variational acoustics- linear\\(both Lagrangians), non-linear from simple Lagrangian}{7}{9} \myline{thin}{blue}
   \ganttbar[
    progress=0,
    name=NONLAG
  ]{(expect intermediate results)To apply the approach developed in TASK XX OUR Lagrangian, compare\\the result with existing models in open literature, and to discuss the physical implications of the result}{6}{12} \myline{thin}{blue}
  \ganttbar[
    progress=0,
    name=REL
  ]{Paper preparation and submission: second variational acoustics-\\linear (both Lagrangians), non-linear from simple Lagrangian}{10}{14} \myline{thin}{blue}
  \ganttbar[
    progress=0,name=POI]{
 To work out a stability analysis for a simple flow example (Poiseuille, Couette or film flow) based\\on the second variation technique with comparison to existing stability results in literature}{14}{18} \myline{thin}{blue}
  \ganttbar[
    progress=0,
    name=FEM
  ]{to figure out a FEM approach for incompressible flow based on the new Lagrangian (but without\\implementing a computer code for the latter) for future applications}{16}{20} \myline{thin}{blue}

  \ganttbar[progress=15]{Thesis writing / and submission}{1}{41} \myline{thin}{blue}
  \ganttbar[progress=15]{Oral Exam}{40}{41} \myline{thin}{blue}

  \ganttlink[link type=s-s]{POI}{FEM}

  %\ganttlink[link type=f-s]{NONLAG}{REL}
  \ganttlink[link type=f-s]{REL}{POI}

  \node [text=blue,font=\Large\bfseries,anchor=east] at (-2,-1.75) {TASKS};
  \draw[line width=2pt,blue] ([yshift=-1cm]current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east);
  \node [font=\Large\bfseries] at ([yshift=0.5cm]current bounding box.north) {Gantt chart showing PhD activity time lines over four month intervals beyond the confirmation review};
\end{ganttchart}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Since the label nodes on the left are right-aligned, I would probably align the text inside to the right as well using `align=right`. I would also align the node with "TASKS" to the right, making its alignment fit the label nodes.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way to do this, if I understood your requests correctly:

[image: result]

Ad 2, as `\ganttbar` expects text, a natural thing to do is to put your label description inside a `\parbox` . Turns out, it's best to define a new command `\pw`, which also handles the boldface. Adjust by chosing a different width than 15cm. // There is some interaction with your header, see below.

```
% put text and boldface into a new command
\newcommand\pw[1]{\parbox{15cm}{\textbf{#1}}}% adjust width by changing the 15cm
```

Ad 1, it's natural to perceive the whole ganttchart as just some tikz-code, which you could use as a nodes content. This is why this extra code arises:

```
\tikz{% <<< TRICK: put ganttchart as node-content, draw borders of node
 \node [draw] {% next follows the content
  \begin{ganttchart}
...
  \end{ganttchart}
  };
...
}
```

Ad 3, now that's all tikz-ish, why not putting an other node which holds your header? With some trial and error for the coordinates this one seems to be reasonable:

```
  \node [draw, red] at (-19, 7) {TASKS};
```

To better find it I left the red frame and text. // !! However, the coordinates will have to change once you adjust the width in `\pw`. There certainly are better ways to do it, like using relative placement (tikzlibrary positioning).

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=5mm]{standalone}% <<< some borders
% Uncomment the following line to allow the usage of graphics (.png, .jpg)
%\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
% Comment the following line to NOT allow the usage of umlauts

\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\title{Gantt chart showing PhD activity time lines over four month intervals beyond the confirmation review}

\usepackage{amsfonts}

% put text and boldface into a new command
\newcommand\pw[1]{\parbox{15cm}{\textbf{#1}}}% adjust width by changing the 15cm

% Start the document
\begin{document}

\definecolor{barblue}{RGB}{153,204,254}
\definecolor{groupblue}{RGB}{51,102,254}
\definecolor{linkred}{RGB}{165,0,33}
\renewcommand\sfdefault{phv}
\renewcommand\mddefault{mc}
\renewcommand\bfdefault{bc}
\setganttlinklabel{s-s}{START-TO-START}
\setganttlinklabel{f-s}{FINISH-TO-START}
\setganttlinklabel{f-f}{FINISH-TO-FINISH}
\sffamily

\tikz{% <<< TRICK: put ganttchart as node-content, draw borders of node
 \node [draw] {% next follows the content
  \begin{ganttchart}[
  [
    canvas/.append style={fill=none, draw=black!5, line width=.75pt},
    hgrid style/.style={*1{draw=black!5, line width=.75pt}},
    vgrid={*1{draw=black!5, line width=.75pt}},
    today=7,
    today rule/.style={
      draw=black!64,
      dash pattern=on 3.5pt off 6.5pt,
      line width=1.5pt
    },
    today label font=\small\bfseries,
    title/.style={draw=none, fill=none},
    title label font=\bfseries\footnotesize,
    title label node/.append style={below=7pt},
    include title in canvas=false,
    bar label font=\mdseries\small\color{black!70},
    bar label node/.append style={left=2cm},
    bar/.append style={draw=none, fill=black!63},
    bar incomplete/.append style={fill=barblue},
    bar progress label font=\mdseries\footnotesize\color{black!70},
    group incomplete/.append style={fill=groupblue},
    group left shift=0,
    group right shift=0,
    group height=.5,
    group peaks tip position=0,
    group label node/.append style={left=.6cm},
    group progress label font=\bfseries\small,
    link/.style={-latex, line width=1.5pt, linkred},
    link label font=\scriptsize\bfseries, 
    link label node/.append style={below left=-2pt and 0pt}
  ]{1}{41}
  \gantttitle[
   ]{QUARTER:\quad1}{2}
  \gantttitle{2022}{12}                        
  \gantttitle{2023}{12}
    \gantttitle{2024}{12} \\  
    \gantttitle{Q3}{4}           
  \gantttitle{Q4}{4}
  \gantttitle{Q1}{4}
  \gantttitle{Q2}{4}
  \gantttitle{Q3}{4}
  \gantttitle{Q4}{4}
  \gantttitle{Q1}{4}
  \gantttitle{Q2}{4}
  \gantttitle{Q3}{4}
  \gantttitle{Q4}{4}
\\

  % --- replace \textbf by \pw in \ganttbar --------
  \ganttbar[
    progress=100,
    name=WBS1A
  ]{\pw{Literature review \& thesis aims clarification }}{1}{4} \\
    \ganttbar[
    progress=100,
    name=WBS1A
  ]{\pw{To carry out a comprehensive check whether the Lagrangian self-consistently implies the correct physics via its resulting Euler-Lagrange equations}}{3}{5}\\
  \ganttbar[
    progress=100,
    name=WBS1D
  ]{\pw{to address HAVING IDENITIFIED X XANNOATE SOLUITON HODGE PR SOMEHTIGN  the short-comings of the article in the BOTHEJM/B-paper}}{4}{6} \\
   \ganttbar[
    progress=0,
    name=WBS1C
  ]{\pw{Paper preperation and submission: Hodge decomposition, suggestion of a Lagrangian and computing the Euler-Lagrange equations}}{6}{8} \\
    \ganttbar[
    progress=100,
    name=WBS1A
  ]{\pw{To work out a systematic approach based on the second variation technique by which in case of compressible flow a linear acoustic model is obtained straight forwardly from an arbitrary Lagrangian}}{3}{4} \\
  \ganttbar[
    progress=100,
    name=WBS1B
  ]{\pw{To apply the forementioned approach developed in to our Lagrangian and compare with classical results }}{4}{5} \\
 
   \ganttbar[
    progress=100,
    name=WBS1C
  ]{\pw{to extend the analysis outlined IN TASK X? to weakly nonlinear acoustic models by amending the second variation technique by cubic terms of the respective Taylor expansion}}{4}{5} \\
  \ganttbar[
    progress=0,
    name=WBS1D
  ]{\pw{Paper preperation and submission: second variational acoustics- linear (both Lagrangians), non-linear from simple Lagrangian}}{7}{9} \\
   \ganttbar[
    progress=0,
    name=NONLAG
  ]{\pw{(expect intermediate results)To apply the approach developed in TASK XX OUR Lagrangian, compare the result with existing models in open literature, and to discuss the physical implications of the result}}{6}{12} \\
  
  \ganttbar[
    progress=0,
    name=REL
  ]{\pw{Paper preperation and submission: second variational acoustics- linear (both Lagrangians), non-linear from simple Lagrangian}}{10}{14} \\
  
  

  
     \ganttbar[
    progress=0,name=POI]{\pw{
 To work out a stability analysis for a simple flow example (Poiseuille, Couette or film flow) based on the second variation technique with comparison to existing stability results in literature}}{14}{18} \\

   
  \ganttbar[
    progress=0,
    name=FEM
  ]{\pw{to figure out a FEM approach for incompressible flow based on the new Lagrangian (but without implementing a computer code for the latter) for future applications }}{16}{20} \\

  \ganttbar[progress=15]{\pw{Thesis writing / and submission}}{1}{41} \\
   \ganttbar[progress=15]{\pw{Oral Exam}}{40}{41}
   

  \ganttlink[link type=s-s]{POI}{FEM}
 
  %\ganttlink[link type=f-s]{NONLAG}{REL}
  \ganttlink[link type=f-s]{REL}{POI}
 
 
\end{ganttchart}
 };
 % HEADER
  \node [draw, red] at (-19, 7) {TASKS};

}

\end{document}
```

**P.S.**: Still not sure how your intended result shall look like, but here are 2 suggestions for further modifications, just to illustrate what you could do in principle. At the end:

```
 % HEADER
  \node  at (-19, 7) {\underline{TASKS}};% underline text
  \draw [blue] (-20, 6.3) to (-4, 6.3) to (-4, -8.35);% draw some lines
```

[image: some lines]

Comment: many thank for your reply ! apologies I also meant I want a line under 'tasks' and, i;ll draw them on in paint and attach what i mean sorry.

Comment: also, the parbox command for the gantt bar titles works for spreading titles over two lines, but if over three, it tends to bunch those ones too close together.thanks

Comment: *i have tried changing the paragraph box size and its ok for the first few (i dont need to space and do \\ it does it autoamtically), but the next ones it is bunching together..seems to be regardless of whether i use \\ or not. also i'd like the titles as close to the gantt chart as possible , shifted right more.

Comment: Right, the bars define the vertical space available and parbox tries to fit all text there. So I see two options. 1) Reduce the text. After all its a label which tends to be short. 2) To increase vertical space per bar, one way to do it is to put a new line (ganttnewline  or so, please find in the manual).

Comment: ty, ganttnewline was not working in my original text.

Comment: FYI, some P.S. edits to illustrate what you could do.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to provide the gantt-chart in a report or so, AND incorporating the idea to shorten the labels, here's an other way to do it. Perhaps it's less a solution and more an illustration of the concept.

Basic steps:

1. use the article class
2. display the title
3. remove ALL definitions and chart options (there was some obscure interaction)
4. keeping the `\gantttitles` for the quarters, but removing the years (my inexperience)
5. putting the `\gantbar` code into a compacter form for better readability in the editor
6. introducing short labels, and explain them after the chart

[image: result]

```
%\documentclass[tikz, border=5mm]{standalone}% <<< some borders
%\documentclass[landscape]{article}% <<< other class
\documentclass[a4]{article}% <<< other class


\usepackage{tikz, pgfgantt}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\title{Gantt chart showing PhD activity time lines over four month intervals beyond the confirmation review}


% put text and boldface into a new command
%\newcommand\pw[1]{\parbox{15cm}{\textbf{#1}}}% adjust width by changing the 15cm
\newcommand\pw[1]{\textbf{#1}}% simpler layout

% Start the document
\begin{document}
 \maketitle% Title at beginning

 \begin{ganttchart}[%removed all definitions for clarity
    expand chart=\textwidth% tame the drawing
  ]{1}{41}
% removed ganttiltle, as there is something strange about it
  \gantttitle{}{1}% a missing leading month
  \gantttitle{Q3}{4}           
  \gantttitle{Q4}{4}
  \gantttitle{Q1}{4}
  \gantttitle{Q2}{4}
  \gantttitle{Q3}{4}
  \gantttitle{Q4}{4}
  \gantttitle{Q1}{4}
  \gantttitle{Q2}{4}
  \gantttitle{Q3}{4}
  \gantttitle{Q4}{4}
  \ganttnewline
  % ~~~ made entries more readable in the editor ~~~~~~~~~~~~
  \ganttbar[progress=100, name=WBS1A]   {\pw{A}}{1}{4} \\
  \ganttbar[progress=100, name=WBS1A]   {\pw{B}}{3}{5} \\
  \ganttbar[progress=100, name=WBS1D]   {\pw{C}}{4}{6} \\
  \ganttbar[progress=0,   name=WBS1C]   {\pw{D}}{6}{8} \\
  \ganttbar[progress=100, name=WBS1A]   {\pw{E}}{3}{4} \\
  \ganttbar[progress=100, name=WBS1B]   {\pw{F}}{4}{5} \\
  \ganttbar[progress=100, name=WBS1C]   {\pw{G}}{4}{5} \\
  \ganttbar[progress=0,   name=WBS1D]   {\pw{H}}{7}{9} \\
  \ganttbar[progress=0,   name=NONLAG]  {\pw{I}}{6}{12} \\
  \ganttbar[progress=0,   name=REL]     {\pw{J}}{10}{14} \\
  \ganttbar[progress=0,   name=POI]     {\pw{K}}{14}{18} \\

  \ganttbar[progress=0,   name=FEM]     {\pw{L}}{16}{20} \\

  \ganttbar[progress=15]                {\pw{M}}{1}{41} \\
  \ganttbar[progress=15]                {\pw{N}}{40}{41}
 \end{ganttchart}

\newpage% start new page
Some more details:
\vspace{2em}% typesetting: put some vertical space

\begin{tabular}{p{1cm}p{11cm}}

A: & Literature review \& thesis aims clarification\\

B: & To carry out a comprehensive check whether the Lagrangian self-consistently implies the correct physics via its resulting Euler-Lagrange equations\\

C: & to address HAVING IDENITIFIED X XANNOATE SOLUITON HODGE PR SOMEHTIGN  the short-comings of the article in the BOTHEJM/B-paper\\

D: & Paper preperation and submission: Hodge decomposition, suggestion of a Lagrangian and computing the Euler-Lagrange equations\\

E: & To work out a systematic approach based on the second variation technique by which in case of compressible flow a linear acoustic model is obtained straight forwardly from an arbitrary Lagrangian\\

F: & To apply the forementioned approach developed in to our Lagrangian and compare with classical results\\

G: & to extend the analysis outlined IN TASK X? to weakly nonlinear acoustic models by amending the second variation technique by cubic terms of the respective Taylor expansion\\

H: & Paper preperation and submission: second variational acoustics- linear (both Lagrangians), non-linear from simple Lagrangian\\

I: & (expect intermediate results)To apply the approach developed in TASK XX OUR Lagrangian, compare the result with existing models in open literature, and to discuss the physical implications of the result\\

J: & Paper preperation and submission: second variational acoustics- linear (both Lagrangians), non-linear from simple Lagrangian\\

K: & To work out a stability analysis for a simple flow example (Poiseuille, Couette or film flow) based on the second variation technique with comparison to existing stability results in literature\\

L: & to figure out a FEM approach for incompressible flow based on the new Lagrangian (but without implementing a computer code for the latter) for future applications\\

M: & Thesis writing / and submission\\

N: & Oral Exam
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

To add, these excluded statements lead to some trouble, which I did not resolve at the moment.

```
\definecolor{barblue}{RGB}{153,204,254}
\definecolor{groupblue}{RGB}{51,102,254}
\definecolor{linkred}{RGB}{165,0,33}
\renewcommand\sfdefault{phv}
\renewcommand\mddefault{mc}
\renewcommand\bfdefault{bc}
\setganttlinklabel{s-s}{START-TO-START}
\setganttlinklabel{f-s}{FINISH-TO-START}
\setganttlinklabel{f-f}{FINISH-TO-FINISH}
\sffamily

...

  [
 %  expand chart=\textwidth,
    canvas/.append style={fill=none, draw=black!5, line width=.75pt},
    hgrid style/.style={*1{draw=black!5, line width=.75pt}},
    vgrid={*1{draw=black!5, line width=.75pt}},
    today=7,
    today rule/.style={
      draw=black!64,
      dash pattern=on 3.5pt off 6.5pt,
      line width=1.5pt
    },
    today label font=\small\bfseries,
    title/.style={draw=none, fill=none},
    title label font=\bfseries\footnotesize,
    title label node/.append style={below=7pt},
    include title in canvas=false,
    bar label font=\mdseries\small\color{black!70},
    bar label node/.append style={left=2cm},
    bar/.append style={draw=none, fill=black!63},
    bar incomplete/.append style={fill=barblue},
    bar progress label font=\mdseries\footnotesize\color{black!70},
    group incomplete/.append style={fill=groupblue},
    group left shift=0,
    group right shift=0,
    group height=.5,
    group peaks tip position=0,
    group label node/.append style={left=.6cm},
    group progress label font=\bfseries\small,
    link/.style={-latex, line width=1.5pt, linkred},
    link label font=\scriptsize\bfseries, 
    link label node/.append style={below left=-2pt and 0pt}
  ]{1}{41}
  \gantttitle[
   ]{QUARTER:\quad1}{2}
  \gantttitle{2022}{12}                        
  \gantttitle{2023}{12}
    \gantttitle{2024}{12} \\
```